# nothing will print in the compiler.

Tags: java

Here's the question I was asked:

Write a complete Java program called CalcTotalPrice. The program must include five methods: 
getSaleTotal, getSalePrice, getSaleWeight, calcTax, and calcShipping.

- getSaleTotal takes no input parameters and returns a double, which is the sale total, and which it computes by calling the other four methods.
- getSalePrice returns a double, which it gets from the user at the command line.
- getSaleWeight returns a double, which it gets from the user at the command line.
- calcTax takes a double as a parameters (the sale price) and returns the tax amount as a double (use 6% as a fixed tax rate).
- calcShipping takes a double as a parameter (the sale weight) and returns the shipping amount as a double (calculate shipping as $10 if weight is less than 10 and $20 if weight is 10 or greater).
- getSaleTotal should print the sale price amount, tax amount, shipping amount, and sale total amount to the command line.

nothing will print in the compiler. Please help me.
Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Kramer1
 */
public class CalcTotalPrice {



/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here


}
public static double getSaleTotal(){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    double price = getSalePrice(in);
    System.out.println(price);
    double tax = calcTax(.06);
    System.out.println(tax);
    double shipping = calcShipping(in.nextDouble());
    System.out.println(shipping);
    double saleTotal = ((price)*tax)+price+shipping;
    System.out.println(saleTotal);
    return saleTotal;
}
public static double getSalePrice(Scanner in){
    double salePrice = in.nextDouble();
    return salePrice;
}
public static double getSaleWeight(Scanner in){
    double saleWeight = in.nextDouble();
    return saleWeight;
}
public static double calcTax(double salePrice){
    double salesTax = .06;
    return salesTax;
}
public static double calcShipping(double saleWeight){
    double amountShipping = 0;
    if (saleWeight < 10){
        amountShipping = 10.; 
    }else if(saleWeight > 10){
        amountShipping = 20.;
    } 
    return amountShipping;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You arent doing anything in your main()
To see the output, you will have to create the Scanner in main and then call appropriate methods.

You need to do some code refactoring. First, move your Scanner to the main method. Then pass it around as an argument to other methods to read data from or read data in main and pass the values directly. I suggest the latter

You also need to declare the variables you use outside the methods and into the class so that their values persist till the end of the program and you will have access to them in various methods. Do declare them static.

Answer (score 0):

You have a main method that is empty - it is not doing anything or calling any code.

Try instantiating your class and calling some methods in it.
it also looks like it is expecting some input from the user.  So also try instantiating a **Scanner** class in your main which can then be passed to some methods.  Remember to also call `in.nextLine();` to flush the input before calling the next `in.nextDouble();`

try

```
Static Double salesPrice = null;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    CalcTotalPrice ctp = new CalcTotalPrice ();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    salesPrice = ctp.getSalesPrice (in);
    in.nextLine();
    //etc

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by calling some methods on in?

Comment: i can't figure it out, but i won't bother you anymore. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: If I spend some time for you, it feels a bit rude that you brush me off like this.  Please explain what you can not understand and maybe I can make it clear for you and the next person who has the same problem as you.

Comment: okay what do you mean by instantiating a Scanner class in main. and how should i call in.nextLine();

Comment: I have updated my answer for you.

Comment: there is a bunch of error messages

Comment: Yes, programming is like that.  Fix one thing and discover the next error.

Comment: i figured out what I was doing wrong. Thanks for your help.